# In a GtkTreeView with multiple rows, how can I programmatically update the model of a GtkCellRendererCombo on a specific line?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am writing an application that uses C/C++ and Glade 3 for the GUI.

A part of the GUI, includes a multi-line `TreeView` where each row represents a user.
On column two there is a `CellRendererCombo` that represents product brands and on column three there is another `CellRendererCombo` that represents the products.

What I am trying to do is: whenever I set the product brand (in column 2) for a user, I want the options of the products `CellRendererCombo` (in column 3) to show only the products of that brand.

I tried updating the model with `g_object_set` but that updates all `CellRendererCombo` in the column.

Comment: ProTip™: Add some asciart whenever you can, especially with UI questions. –––
So if you say you tried `g_object_set` you mean `g_object_set (renderer, "model", some_combobox_option_model, NULL)` right?

Comment: @drahnr I tried `g_object_set (renderer, "text-column", 0, "editable", TRUE, "has-entry", TRUE, "model", NULL, NULL);` to remove the contents of the renderer that signalled and it was applied to the whole column.

Comment: The issue here is that a GtkCellRenderer always renders the whole colum - I think you have to derive from GtkCellRendererCombo with multiple Filters for your model, depending on the combobox selection in your 2nd column of that very same row.

Comment: @drahnr - you're right that the cell renderer renders the whole column but you can bind differernt properties for each row (see my answer below) - there is no need to derive a new renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Glade:

1. What I needed to do was add a new column of type `GtkTreeModel` to the model of my `TreeView`. Unfortunately `GtkTreeModel` is not part of the drop-down list that Glade provides when you create a column, so I manually typed `GtkTreemodel` to the type column.
2. Then, I edited the `CellRendererCombo` that represents the products and defined as a model the column that I just created.

In the source code:

1. When I load the data to the model of the `TreeView`, I create for each row a new `ListStore` and store a reference to it in the `TreeView` model.

   ```
   gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE(data->liststore_analysis), &iter, COLUMN_MODEL, GTK_LIST_STORE(data->liststore_products), -1);
   ```
2. When I change the value of the `CellRendererCombo` that represents the brands, I update the rows in the model for the other `CellRendererCombo`.

   ```
   GtkListStore * list = GTK_LIST_STORE(data->liststore_products);
   GtkTreeIter iter;
   const char * openmoko[] = {"Neo 1973","Neo FreeRunner","Dash Express","3D7K","WikiReader"};
   int i, openmokoModels = sizeof (openmoko) / sizeof (*openmoko);
   for (i = 0; i < openmokoModels; i++){
       gtk_list_store_append(list, &iter);
       gtk_list_store_set(list, &iter, 0, openmoko[i], -1);
   }
   ```

Thank you guys for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you found using `g_object_set` to set the model for the combobox sets the model for the whole column. What you need to do is have a column (COLUMN_COMBOBOX_MODEL) in the model you're using for the treeview which stores a reference to the model you want to use in the combobox for each row and do something like `gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute (column, combobox_renderer, "model", COLUMN_COMBOBOX_MODEL)` to map the `model` property of the cellrenderer to the right model for each row. You can still use g_object_set to set the `"text-column"` and `"editable"` properties of the cell renderer.

Comment: Can you provide a documentation link, didn't know that was possible.

Comment: All the documentation for gtk is available at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable. I would recommend reading the [treeview overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TreeWidget.html) and the documentation for [GtkTreeViewColumn](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) to start with. If you want the documentation available locally on linux then you can install the devhelp and gtk3-doc packages from your distribution.

Comment: I have all that, it seems I never read that part of `GtkTreeViewColumn` docs

Comment: @PhillipWood What I tried is: using Glade I added a new column to the `ListStore` that has the type `GObject`. I added a couple of rows to it and filled almost all data. I was not able to set the objects for the new column, when I clicked on the empty box nothing happened.

Comment: So, I tried the following code to assign the model for the first row before before calling `gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, data );` but it was unsuccesfull:
`model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (GTK_TREE_VIEW(data->treeview_analysis));
gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(GTK_TREE_MODEL(data->liststore_analysis), &iter);
gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE (model), &iter, 2,GTK_LIST_STORE(data->liststore_products), -1);`

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your code and glade file. Are you calling `gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute` to set the model for each row? In your code above does `model == data->liststore_analysis` ?